# Azure B2C React SPA dose not providing access token

Tags: node.js, single-page-application, azure-ad-b2c, access-token, webapi

I am working on my first project of connecting Azure B2C with MERN App. I wanted to Sign In using Azure B2C and authorise my web API using the Access Token.

I configured everything and applied configurations to this s[ample React tutorial provide by their documentation](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-react-tutorial/tree/main/3-Authorization-II/2-call-api-b2c).

The problem arises while calling the Web API. The Web API call are sending without any token. When I check the code, acquireTokenSilent function returning empty accessToken from response.

```
instance.acquireTokenSilent({
                scopes: protectedResources.apiHello.scopes,
                account: account
            }).then(async (response) => {
                console.log(response)
```

The Request is:
[image]

Even though I looked many forums and Microsoft technical forums, no answer is not working.

But what I noticed is, it is requesting for `grant_type: authorization_code` but am not seeing access token in the response. Posting here the API call, request and response.

[image]

[image]

The Response is producing id_token but not access token,

[image]

I gave grant permission in the SPA App permission for task.read scope. I tried everything but I am still receiving the access token as empty. How could I fix this issue?

Comment: What is the exact scope you are passing to acquireTokenSilent?

Comment: please refer this https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-register-spa.md

Comment: @derisen: Custom scope... https://<tenant>.omicrosoft.com/pmapi/task.read

Comment: @Venkatesan Even I followed the step refereed in the documentation, I am getting the same

Comment: @SmithDwayne Please check the posted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:**

I registered one Azure AD B2C application for **app1** and added scopes(task.read) as below:

[image]

Now I created one SPA registration and added **API permissions** by granting **consent** like this:
[image]

I created **`Sign up and sign in policy`** and ran the user flow as below:

[image]

Please Check authentication and access token and id token:

[image]

I signed in  as user it gave me auth code in address bar.

```
https://<tenant name >.b2clogin.com/<tenant name> .onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_susi&client_id=<app id>&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms&scope=openid%20https%3A%2F%2F<tenant name>.onmicrosoft.com tasks.read&response_type=code&prompt=login&code_challenge_method=S256&code_challenge=<challenge paramater>
```

[image]

**I generated the access token via Postman with commands like this:**

```
POST  https://tenant.b2clogin.com/tenant.onmicrosoft.com/policy/oauth2/v2.0/token

grant_type: authorization_code
client_id: SPA_appid
scope:  https://tenant.onmicrosoft.com/app1/task.read
redirect_uri: redirect_uri
code: code
code_verifier: code_verifier
```

***Postman***

[image]
[image]

When I decode the token i getting **`scp`** in jwt .ms

[image]

Comment: Nice. now I am getting the access token. Earlier I created the Scope(task.read) in Web API app and linked it with SPA authentication permission. Now as per your example, I created the Scope under the SPA app itself and able to get the access token now. But now when I try to verify the token in my Web API through passport, it throws me `authentication failed due to: In Strategy.prototype.jwtVerify: none of the scopes in token is accepted`

Comment: It worked :) After I edited my scope in my web api config

Comment: Please do not recommend checking ID and Access Token checkboxes on the Authentication blade, unless you intend to use the less secure implicit flow (which is not recommended).